# How To Send Email With PHP 5-5.5.9 Smtp Send( ) Function On Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: email, smtp, pear, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.5

I want to send e-mail on ubuntu 14.04 with smtp php. But I can't send e-mail because `smtp-->send` function doesn't work. So that I decided to install pear mail packages. But when ı want to install php pear mail packages on my terminal the error occurs.

For example error occurs as below when ı entered `sudo pear install Mail_Mime` command to my terminal.

```
downloading Mail_Mime-1.8.9.tgz ...
Starting to download Mail_Mime-1.8.9.tgz (33,796 bytes)
.........done: 33,796 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/tmp/pear/install/Mail_Mime-1.8.9.tgz"
Download of "pear/Mail_Mime" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pear/Mail_Mime"
Download failed
install failed
```

Because of this errors I decided to upgrade the pear which is in my system.I entered "pear upgrade" command the error occurs as below..

```
pear/pear dependency package "pear/XML_Util" downloaded version 1.2.3 is not the
recommended version 1.2.1, but may be compatible, use --force to install
pear/XML_Util cannot be installed, conflicts with installed packages
No valid packages found
upgrade failed
```

I executed "pear clear-cache, pear update-channels" commands before " pear upgrade" command. All commands executed but "pear upgrade" didn't work because of errors as above.

`$mail = @$smtp->send(.. , .., ..);` function doesn't work. So that mail isn't sended.This `send()` function worked with 1.9.4 version of pear, 5.3.10 version of php and ubuntu 12.04. But it doesn't work with 1.9.4 version of pear,5.5.9 php and ubuntu 14.04.

I added `"sendmail_path"` part to `php.ini` file.But again I couldn't install pear mail packages on terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install pear mail package on ubuntu 14.04. Because pear didn't upload version for ubuntu 14.04. You can use swift mail package instead of smtp mail package with php in ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

> could not extract the package.xml file from "/tmp/pear/install/Mail_Mime-1.8.9.tgz"

You're hitting a bug of Archive_Tar in relation with PHP 5.5.x.

Apply the patch as I [described in my blog](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/pear-php-5.5.htm).